# Wait for keystroke or a maximum of t seconds in MATLAB GUI via GUIDE

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I am working on a MATLAB GUI in GUIDE which is going to be part of a dual task experiment. I basically have a GUI with two boxes where an integer between 1 and 10 (randomly chosen) is going to pop in one of them (randomly chosen). Based on the number they are supposed to press either the left arrow or the right arrow key on the keyboard (even or odd) and I need to save their input, reaction time etc. When they press a key I wait for a period between 0.5 and 2s and  choose the box and number to display randomly again and display it and they have to press again etc. So far so good, I use the WindowKeyPressFcn

```
function figure1_WindowKeyPressFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

switch eventdata.Key    
    case 'leftarrow'
        save and choose rand number and box and display
    case 'rightarrow'
        save and choose rand number and box and display
    otherwise        
end
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Now, I have 2 questions.

1) What I actually need to do is give them a maximum of 2.5 s to press a key. That means that I want to wait for a keypress or a maximum of 2.5 s and if they don't press anything in those 2.5 s change the number and box again and mark their reply as wrong. How do I do this? Since WindowKeyPressFcn is only activated when a key press occurs I need to have this code outside of it but where (this is my first guide GUI...)?

2) Like I mentioned, after a keypress I want the gui to wait for 0.5 - 2 s  before displaying  another random number and waiting for input. What I can do now though is that I can keep pressing one of the 2 arrow buttons and the WindowKeyPressFcn is always triggered and the boxes remain black because the function is always ending up in this 0.5 - 2s break period. Is there a way to block it so that it has to wait for another number to be shown? The code for the random number generation and showing in the box (so set(handles.eo_numberr, 'string', num2str(number)); ) is in the 2 case's of the switch shown above.
Thanks

---

Ok, so I looked into timer objects and have a timer now and it works fine, mostly... Here is the code of the relevant functions:

Openingfcn:
    function dual_task_gui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

```
set(handles.eo_numberr, 'string', '');
set(handles.eo_numberl, 'string', '');
% define handles for saving relevant data
handles.rand_numbers = [];
% handles.number = number;
handles.responses = [];% 0 for even 1 for odd
handles.responsetimes = [];
handles.firstiteration = 0;
handles.timer = timer('ExecutionMode','singleShot','StartDelay',2.5,'TimerFcn', {@update_boxes,hObject});

handles.timer.StartFcn = @timerstart_fcn;
handles.timer.StopFcn = @timerstop_fcn;

% Choose default command line output for dual_task_gui
handles.output = hObject;
% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Keypressfcn:

```
% --- Executes on key press with focus on figure1 or any of its controls.
function figure1_WindowKeyPressFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)


if handles.firstiteration %if it's not the first iteration save the responses
    switch eventdata.Key
        case 'leftarrow'
            % stop timer and evaluate
            if strcmp(get(handles.timer, 'Running'), 'on')
                stop(handles.timer);
            end
            % get the reaction time and save it

            set(handles.eo_numberl, 'string', '');
            set(handles.eo_numberr, 'string', '');
            pause_dur = 0.5 + (2-0.5).*rand(1);% pause between 0.5 and 2s
            pause(pause_dur);
            % compare number and response and save both
            handles.responses = [handles.responses,1];
            handles.rand_numbers = [handles.rand_numbers,handles.number];
            handles.number = randi(10,1,1);% generate random number
            % choose window to show number in
            choose_window = round(rand(1));
            if choose_window == 0
                set(handles.eo_numberl, 'string', num2str(handles.number));
                set(handles.eo_numberr, 'string', '');
            elseif choose_window == 1;
                set(handles.eo_numberr, 'string', num2str(handles.number));
                set(handles.eo_numberl, 'string', '');
            end
        case 'rightarrow'
            % stop timer and evaluate
            if strcmp(get(handles.timer, 'Running'), 'on')
                stop(handles.timer);
            end
            % get the reaction time and save it
            set(handles.eo_numberl, 'string', '');
            set(handles.eo_numberr, 'string', '');
            pause_dur = 0.5 + (2-0.5).*rand(1);% pause between 0.5 and 2s
            pause(pause_dur);
            % compare number and response and save both
            handles.responses = [handles.responses,0];
            handles.rand_numbers = [handles.rand_numbers,handles.number];
            handles.number = randi(10,1,1);% generate random number
            % choose window to show number in
            choose_window = round(rand(1));
            if choose_window == 0
                set(handles.eo_numberl, 'string', num2str(handles.number));
                set(handles.eo_numberr, 'string', '');
            elseif choose_window == 1;
                set(handles.eo_numberr, 'string', num2str(handles.number));
                set(handles.eo_numberl, 'string', '');
            end
        otherwise
            return;
    end
    % start timer again
    % Only start timer if it is not running
    if strcmp(get(handles.timer, 'Running'), 'off')
        start(handles.timer);
    end
    % if it takes more than 2.5s to press a button move on to the
    % next number
else
    % if it's the first keystroke, don't take reaction time into account
    handles.firstiteration =1;
    pause_dur = 0.5 + (2-0.5).*rand(1);% pause between 0.5 and 2s
    pause(pause_dur);
    handles.number = randi(10,1,1);% generate random number
    % choose window to show number in
    choose_window = round(rand(1));
    if choose_window == 0
        set(handles.eo_numberl, 'string', num2str(handles.number));
        set(handles.eo_numberr, 'string', '');
    elseif choose_window == 1;
        set(handles.eo_numberr, 'string', num2str(handles.number));
        set(handles.eo_numberl, 'string', '');
    end
    % start timer again
    start(handles.timer);    
    % if it takes more than 2.5s to press a button move on to the
    % next number
end
guidata(hObject, handles);

function timerstart_fcn(hObject,eventdata)
disp('Start timer');

function timerstop_fcn(hObject,eventdata)
disp('Stop timer');
```

Timerfcn and close fcn:

```
function update_boxes(hObject,eventdata,hfigure)
disp('timerfcn');
handles = guidata(hfigure);
% stop timer
if strcmp(get(handles.timer, 'Running'), 'on')
    stop(handles.timer);
end

set(handles.eo_numberl, 'string', '');
set(handles.eo_numberr, 'string', '');
pause_dur = 0.5 + (2-0.5).*rand(1);% pause between 0.5 and 2s
pause(pause_dur);
handles.responses = [handles.responses,2];
handles.rand_numbers = [handles.rand_numbers,handles.number];
handles.number = randi(10,1,1);% generate random number
% choose window to show number in
choose_window = round(rand(1));

if choose_window == 0
    set(handles.eo_numberl, 'string', num2str(handles.number));
    set(handles.eo_numberr, 'string', '');
elseif choose_window == 1;
    set(handles.eo_numberr, 'string', num2str(handles.number));
    set(handles.eo_numberl, 'string', '');
end
% start timer again
% Only start timer if it is not running
if strcmp(get(handles.timer, 'Running'), 'off')
    start(handles.timer);
end
% if it takes more than 2.5s to press a button move on to the
% next number
% guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes when user attempts to close figure1.
function figure1_CloseRequestFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to figure1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
if strcmp(get(handles.timer, 'Running'), 'on')
    stop(handles.timer);
end
% Destroy timer
delete(handles.timer)
% Hint: delete(hObject) closes the figure
delete(hObject);
```

Sorry about the length,  but the relevant parts for the question below are the timer start and stop calls I think. Now the question:
One scenario doesn't work yet. Let's say the test subject fails to press left or right in 2.5 s. Then the timerfcn gets triggered and a new random number shown which is fine. However, if he fails to press a key again (for 2.5s) nothing happens - the timerfcn doesn't get called - even though I start the timer at the end of it seems to get stopped somewhere. It works fine if he fails non-consecutively. I don't understand why this is the case. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Create a timer object that calls the "next image" callback after e.g. 2.5 seconds, and that you kill if a button has been pressed before.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and write how it went.

Comment: Jonas, you should "answer" the question.

Comment: So I tried it out and I still have a problem, I posted it below.